# Keeping the same window size with dynamic amount of plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, grid

I'm displaying a dynamic number of plots in a tkinter grid. I want the the same window size each time no matter how many plots are shown. I want only the plots to resize while maintaining the their relative size to the figure. With the code below the window size is resized according to the number of plots shown.

What I tried so far:

1. `maxsize` prevents the window to become too big but the figure can be bigger than the window and is just cut.
2. `set_size_inches` does absolutely nothing and the problem remains.
3. `rcParams` does nothing, too.

To reproduce the problem I added two different datasets in size in the code: `cols_1, x1, y1` and `cols_2, x2, y2`. You can switch between them easily by changing the number in
`cols, x, y = cols_1, x1, y1`

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import numpy as np

cols_1 = 3
x1 = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
y1 = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3], [3, 1, 2]]

cols_2 = 5
x2 = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
y2 = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3], [3, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2]]

# switch between ..._1 and ..._2 to see difference
cols, x, y = cols_1, x1, y1

root = tk.Tk()

array = []

for i in range(0, len(x)):
    array.append(i)
    array_2 = [array[i: i + cols] for i in range(0, len(x), cols)] # generates array of the length of the number of entries

for i in range(0, len(x)):
    fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(2, 2))
    fig.set_facecolor("grey")
    ax = fig.add_subplot()
    ax.scatter(x[i], y[i])

    #deactivated axes and ticks to see the arrangement better
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

    # this part finds the row and column number (row_i and column_i) of every item in x/y array to distribute the plots in grid
    array_2 = [array[i: i + cols] for i in range(0, len(x), cols)]
    array_3 = np.array(array_2)
    target = i
    row, col = np.nonzero(array_3 == target)
    row_i = int(row)
    column_i = int(col)
    chart1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
    chart1.get_tk_widget().grid(row=row_i, column=column_i)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you looked at `root.geometry(...)` and `root.resizable(...)`?

Comment: @TheLizzard I tried that quickly but the same problem remains.

Comment: You need to dynamically calculate your `figsize`. It accepts float values so you can be as precise as required.

Comment: @HenryYik Could you be more precise, please? That's also something I tried already. But I haven't found a formula which keeps the figsize constant.